# javascript, dojo, building dialogs in jsp's with enclosures

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am using closures in dojo dialogs to keep functions and variables from colliding.

I have a jsp page that includes a complex dialog.  It is mostly working.  Just one really annoying detail.  if the widget changes how do I notify a handler method?   we want as much of the java script for the dialog to be kept within the closure.

Since the popup appears in multiple locations I want future programmers to be able to replace myVar with anything.  Is there a way to determine what to correctly put in the onChange

------jsp page-----

`var myVar = new MyNewPopupStuff(42);

myVar.contstrucDialog();

......

includeTemplate template="myDialog.jsp"

.....`

--------myDialog.jsp----

`< script type="text/javascript" src="my.js"/>`

.....

< div  id="myDialogData" dojotype="dijit.layout.ContentPane"  region="right" splitter="true" class="data" style=" width:50%; "  > <\/div>
....

--------my.js file----

```
function MyNewPopupStuff(param){

     this.contstrucDialog = function()
     .......
     while( more widgets to add){
           fieldHolder=dojo.byId("myDialogData"
     addWidget(widgetName,myDialogData);
     }

     addWidget = function(fieldHolder, widgetName){
     // need to print the name of the variable in "myVar.bar()" (myVar or what ever it may be)
     dojo.place(newLabel, fieldHolder);
        var newField = new dijit.form.ValidationTextBox({
        id: "i"+contactTypeId,
        name: widgetName,
        value: value,
        trim: true,
       **onChange:**??????when the widget is mofied I want to call the below modifyOnChange not some other modify on change  I think I want something like myVar.modifyOnChange????

    });
    }


    this.modifyOnChange = function()
     {
         alert("modified");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a framework that implements the EcmaScript 5 bind method for functions, use:

```
onChange: modifyOnChange.bind(this),
```

else implement it yourself with:

```
onChange: (function(self) {
    return function() {
        return modifyOnChange.apply(self, arguments);
    }
})(this),
```

`myVar.modifyOnChange` might work, but what's the point of abstracting stuff into a class if you then tie the code to the global you expect to be holding the object? And what happens if somebody wants to add another MyNewPopupStuff object?